# What if the Earth's oceans are added to Mars?

Tags: planets, water

Imagine if all the water of the Earth's Oceans were added instantaneously to the Martian surface. 
What wouldhappen in 10 mins? In 10 years? In 1000 years? In 1 billion years?

*Would life form?*

Comment: Mandatory [XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/54/) reference

Comment: It isn't in the What If? book.

Comment: This one - https://what-if.xkcd.com/54/

Comment: "What would happen ... in 1 billion years?" Um... Lots of stuff. For example, a few thousand stars would die, a bunch more asteroids would collide, and life may appear somewhere in the universe. Even if we restrict the scope to one planet, 1 billion years of development and change is far too much to cover in a single answer.

Comment: Hi, rubixphys12. Several of your recent questions have been closed, for various reasons. In many cases, they were not necessarily about worldbuilding (see our [help] for more details) or were insufficiently constrained. Please also see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), especially the information about subjectivity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Water added to mars would freeze over *and* sublimate into the thin air. What this new equilibreium atmosphere does to the temperature would probably be greenhouse-like, but the ice surface would have a cooling effect as sublight is reflected.

Water and gasses in general are lost from Mars over geologic time scales. But that is a significant depth of water to get rid of, so I suppose it will stay like that for a billion years or so.